# Test statement containing parent scope variable using Karma

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am testing my controller which has a parent scope variable reference. But it is giving variable undefined error.

**subscription (controller)**

```
var vm = this;
var userId=$scope.$parent.vm.userId;
var simId=$scope.$parent.vm.simId;
```

**subscriptionSpec (spec file)**

```
describe('subscription controller',function (){
    var SubscriptionListCtrl,scope;
    beforeEach(module('app'));

    beforeEach(inject(function($controller,$compile,SubscriptionService,dataTableConfigService,commonUtilityService){
    scope={};
    scope.vm={};

    SubscriptionListCtrl=$controller("SubscriptionListCtrl",{$scope:scope,$compile:$compile,SubscriptionService:SubscriptionService,dataTableConfigService:dataTableConfigService,commonUtilityService:commonUtilityService});

    }));
});
```

**Karma Jasmine Error**

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'vm' of undefined
```

This comes because of the controller statement

> var userId=$scope.$parent.vm.userId;

Also if I replace the $scope.$parent.vm.userId with actual value then it will not give any error.

How do I write the test case for this line?

Answer (score 2):

Try with mocking the parent scope like

```
describe('subscription controller',function (){
    var SubscriptionListCtrl,scope;
    beforeEach(module('app'));

    beforeEach(inject(function($controller,$rootScope,$compile,SubscriptionService,dataTableConfigService,commonUtilityService){
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    scope.$parent = {vm: {userId: 1, simId: 2}};
    scope.vm={};

    SubscriptionListCtrl=$controller("SubscriptionListCtrl",{$scope:scope,$compile:$compile,SubscriptionService:SubscriptionService,dataTableConfigService:dataTableConfigService,commonUtilityService:commonUtilityService});

    }));
});
```

Comment: It was giving the same error. Now I used the $stateParams to get the variable instead of using the $parent scope variables. So running the test cases didn't throw any error. Anyways thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

To extend vpsingh016 answer what should be done to give wanted result is define parent controller and parent scope and when initializing define $scope.$parent = $parentScope. For example :

```
describe('Controller: TestController', function () {

    beforeEach(module('App'));

    var $controller, $scope, $parentController, $parentScope;

    beforeEach(inject(function (_$controller_, _$rootScope_) {

        $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
        $parentScope = _$rootScope_.$new();
        $scope.$parent = $parentScope;

        $parentController = _$controller_('ParentController', {'$scope': $parentScope});
        $controller = _$controller_('TestController', {'$scope': $scope});
    }));
    it('should get $parent variable', function () {
        var userId=$scope.$parent.vm.userId;
        var simId=$scope.$parent.vm.simId;
    })
});
```